# ggplot2: Trim wasted space on stacked horizontal bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a horizontally stacked bar chart that is almost perfect, sans the wasted vertical space.

```
ggplot(category_df, aes(x = OPERATION, y = CATEGORY_LOT_COUNT, fill=HOLD_CATEGORY, label=CATEGORY_LOT_COUNT)) +
            geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width=0.1) +
            xlab("") +
            theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                  legend.title.align = 0.5,
                  legend.direction = 'horizontal',
                  legend.position = 'bottom') +
            geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=10, color='white', face = 'bold') +
            coord_fixed(ratio = .2) +
            coord_flip()
```

Produces:

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

As you can see above I tried to use `coord_fixed` with no success.

thx

Comment: Try with reducing the height of your plotting window or the height used to export your chart (And of course reset the width of the bars to the default .9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you export the graphic. In RStudio you might drag and adjust the plots-window prior to exporting. For anything else than a quick export, however, I would recommend to use `ggplot2::ggsave()` and set the width, height and unit-parameters according to your desire.
As Stefan pointed out: `width=0.1` will shrink the bar width to something rather slim.

NB: This is a non-reproducible example, as we don't have access to `category_df`.

Comment: Thanks @stefan and @Beni, I ended up removing my bar `width` argument and then just set the width of the `renderPlot` function

```renderPlot({ card_plots[[plot_name]] }, height = 100)```